# Grothendieck's complete absorption in mathematical research

Tags: mathematicians, biographical-details, grothendieck

I have recently been interested in the history of French Mathematics especially in Grothendieck and his school. I have also been fascinated with Grothendieck's personality.

It is known that during Grothendieck's IHES years is his dedication to mathematics was legendary as attested by many of his colleagues. However, I have also heard that during times he would be so concentrated on mathematical research that he would forget/neglect
to sleep and eat.

Is that true?

Could you provide references.

P.S.
I am interested in this questions since I am studying psychology and examining the personalities of influential mathematicians. I have to write on the subject. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the question about Grothendieck, someone previously unknown to me. I haven nothing to share about him. What may be of interest is the story of Paul Dirac, *the strangest man* in 20th c physics who gets a nice biography here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPwo1XsKKXg&pp=ygURUGF1bCBEaXJhYyBncmFoYW0%3D

Comment: The [MacTutor entry on Grothendieck](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Grothendieck/) includes two relevant quotations from colleagues - namely Valentin Poénaru and Ronnie Brown.

Comment: See also this article by Allyn Jackson: https://www.ams.org/notices/200410/fea-grothendieck-part2.pdf